# C++ message passing like Windows's ::SendMessage / ::PostMessage

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm refactoring a program to make it less dependent on Windows-specific constructs. The threading model is the 'traditional' Windows GUI model: there is one 'main' GUI thread which does only very short operations, to keep the GUI responsive; all longer tasks are done in 'worker' threads. All worker threads communicate with the gui thread only, and they do so via ::SendMessage and ::PostMessage (SendMessage is blocking, and PostMessage is not, for those not familiar with the Windows API). 'Notification' style messages, 'like hey I'm done processing', or messages for which all parameters can be fitted into 2 32-bit values (the parameters to Send/PostMessage) are send with PostMessage, because there is no data access that needs to be synchronized; messages for which a lot of data has to be passed use SendMessage, and the gui thread then (quickly) copies everything it needs before it does 'real' processing (or passes that 'real' processing off to another worker thread). This way, there is never concurrent access to the same data. It has some restrictions but it has worked for us so far; the main advantage is that it's such a simple model, you almost never have to think hard on what could happen or do explicit synchronization because there is never shared access to data.

The 'only' restriction that I want to lift is that this model is for one-way communication only: it's from workers to the gui thread. It has worked for our purposes so far, but I want to move to a model where all thread are equal and any thread can 'post' a message to any other thread, bi-directional; then on top of this, I want to build something that checks that 'worker threads' only communicate with the 'main thread' and vice versa; and never 'worker threads' between each other. This way we will have flexibility in the future to re-use the mechanism in other use cases where threads do need to communicate n:n.

So now my question is: how do I replicate this behavior using either c++11 or the boost thread libraries? Ideally, I would have a global function or member of a singleton which can be called from any thread, with as the first parameter an id of some sort of the thread to 'call into', maybe some sort of 'message id' (messages would have to be registered first, much like RegisterUserMessage() in win32) and a void* that is specific to the message. The receiver would be responsible for casting and interpreting the message. Then somehow a message handling method is called in the context of the 'receiving' thread.

So I'm thinking maybe a base class 'ThreadBase' from which other classes derive; 'ThreadBase' would provide a pure virtual function 'HandleMessage(unsigned int msg_id, void* data)' or so. Maybe this 'ThreadBase' would itself derive from std::thread? Or have an std::thread member? Then in (for this example) main() I'd do:

```
ThreadManager::RegisterMessage(1234);  // 'Thread1 is done'
Thread1 t1(1); // Thread1 and Thread2 both derived from 'ThreadBase'
Thread2 t2(2); // Construction of t1 and t2 would immediately start the thread; alternatively they could have a Run() member?
```

Then from anywhere in t1 I could do:

```
MyData data;
ThreadManager::SendMessage(2, 1234, (void*)&data);
```

And this would call Thread2::HandleMessage() with arguments '1234' and '&data'.

I hope I'm making sense here - I think from the wording of my question it's clear that I'm not very familiar with multi-threading beyond the win32 API. Does this idea even make sense? Drawbacks I'm overlooking? How could this be implemented using threading primitives? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Your question clearly doesn't fit into SO questions format ;), but I won't hold you to that.

I will try to explain something about threading model in C++. The firtst thing to remember is that it is actually modelled on Posix threads. So you can find Posix stuff there, but not Windows-specific stuff. In particular, it means it lacks any built-in support for messaging. The closes you can have is a conditional variable, but you can only wait on single conditional variable, and can not multiplex. To use messaging, you need to implement your own message queue, or use third-party library (boost certainly has one, as well as a bunch of other libraries).